# How to update a MongoDB collection automatically every midnight?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I currently have an SPA built with MERN and I want to improve it further by adding a scheduled update to a particular collection in my MongoDB database by setting a `boolean` field in all of the documents in a collection to false every midnight.

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to accomplish this?

I want to be able to scale it as well at some point - for example, have a value saved in a document in another collection to indicate the time where these `boolean` fields will be invalidated in the front end?

I'm using a MERN stack. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can achieve this by using cron job in nodejs follow these link for examples https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-in-node-js-897215e2e5d3 https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`cron job`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

```js
const moment = require('moment');
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

const updateCollections = async ()=>{
  await someQueriesServices()
}

new CronJob('0 0 * * *', async () => {
  await updateCollections()
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

or you can use `setInterval`

```js
const timeInSec = moment().endOf('day').valueOf()
const Interval = Date.now() - timeInSec;

setInterval(async ()=>{
    await updateCollections()
},Interval)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use node-schedule

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```